# Return false not working after ajax call to block HREF value of anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a link like this.

```
<a class="case" href="/communication/index">Link Name</a>
```

And I have a handler for this.

```
 $('.case').on('click',function () {
        checkCaseIsParked(this);
  });
```

And inside this checkCaseIsParked method, I have ajax call and on success, I compare the return value and if it's true then I want to prevent it from going to next site i.e. a link on href.

```
success: function (result, status, xhr) {
      if (result) { return false; }
            else { return true };
    }
```

I tried it returning false but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return false` must happen synchronously. Since you don't know whether the redirect should happen until after the response comes back, you should `return false` (or `preventDefault()`) regardless, and then, if the response says that the redirect is OK, manually `click()` it:

```js
const checkCaseIsParked = elm => {
  console.log('processing');
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (elm.id === 'case') {
      elm.click();
    } else {
      console.log("failed");
    }
  }, 1000);
};

$('#case, #case2').on('click', function(event) {
  if (event.originalEvent.isTrusted) {
    // event was triggered by user input, not by Javascript
    checkCaseIsParked(this);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="case" href="/communication/index">pass</a>
<a id="case2" href="/communication/index">fail</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response but in my case, that link is not with id it has class as it is on every row of the table. Prevent default is working but now in a case of condition is false it is not moving to the next site. How can i class click event.

Comment: Please post all relevant information and requirements in the question itself (ideally, when you post the question, not after answers have come in), so we have a [MCVE] to debug. Having the handler handle multiple elements looks to work fine in the snippet, see how there's both `#case` and `#case2`

Comment: It's working, I missed adding a condition to check if the event is original. Thank you.